# Center input[checkbox] in flex div

Tags: css, checkbox, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm making a side menu with some filters, for this purpose I need to create a row that has input checkbox and next to it some text. My problem is that when the text is too big the checkbox doesn't center in the flex container. I tried using

> align-items: baseline

but it didn't work.

Current:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

```
<div class="container" style="width:100px; height: 40px;">
  <div class="little-container mt-3">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-baseline">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <span class="font-weight-bold flex-grow-1">Just a really big text Just a really big text Just a really big text Just a really big text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle I'm using bootstrap 4 https://jsfiddle.net/ccastro95/5qc2w1n4/7/

Thank you.

Comment: `align-items-center` instead of `align-items-baseline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
```

add display block to the span

```
<span class="d-block">
```

Comment: you don't need to use flex-row as it is the default.

Comment: you don't need to make the spam block since it's a flex item

Comment: ah right! tthats correct

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-baseline">
```

use:

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row" style="align-items:center">
```

I recommend taking a look at CSS Tricks' fantastic resource on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/